# unable to delete a node in double linked list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

I am trying this without a head/start pointer which would generally hold the address of first node. I have 3 nodes here from which I am trying to delete last node, but its not happening. I might be wrong in my logic and this is my first linked list program, so please help me!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct dll {
    struct dll* prev;
    int data;
    struct dll* next;
};

int main() {
    struct dll* p1, *p2, *p3, *temp;
    p1 = malloc(sizeof(struct dll));
    p2 = malloc(sizeof(struct dll));
    p3 = malloc(sizeof(struct dll));
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct dll));
    p1->prev = NULL;
    p1->data = 1;
    p1->next = p2;
    p2->prev = p1;
    p2->data = 2;
    p2->next = p3;
    p3->prev = p2;
    p3->data = 3;
    p3->next = NULL;
    struct dll* add = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    printf("add of p1::%p add of p2::%p add of p3::%p add of p1->prev::%p add "
           "of p1->next::%p add of p2->prev::%p add of p2->next::%p add of "
           "p3->prev::%p add of p3->next::%p\n",
           p1, p2, p3, p1->prev, p1->next, p2->prev, p2->next, p3->prev,
           p3->next);
    while (p1->next != NULL) {
        count++;
        p1 = p1->next;
    }
    printf("no of nodes %d\n", count + 1);
    puts("enter the addresss of node to delete it");
    scanf("%p", &add);
    while (p1->next != NULL) {
        if (p1->next == add) {
            temp = p1->next;
            p1->next = NULL;
            free(temp);
            temp = NULL;
        } else
            p1 = p1->next;
    }
    puts("after deletion attempted");
    printf("add of p1::%p add of p2::%p add of p3::%p add of p1->prev::%p add "
           "of p1->next::%p add of p2->prev::%p add of p2->next::%p add of "
           "p3->prev::%p add of p3->next::%p\n",
           p1, p2, p3, p1->prev, p1->next, p2->prev, p2->next, p3->prev,
           p3->next);

    while (p1->next != NULL) {
        count++;
        p1 = p1->next;
    }
    printf("no of nodes %d\n", count + 1);
    free(p1);
    p1 = NULL;
    free(p2);
    p2 = NULL;
    free(p3);
    p3 = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

**output::::**

```
add of p1::0x9605008 add of p2::0x9605018 add of p3::0x9605028 add of p1->prev::(nil) add of p1->next::0x9605018 add of p2->prev::0x9605008 add of p2->next::0x9605028 add of p3->prev::0x9605018 add of p3->next::(nil)

no of nodes 3

enter the addresss of node to delete it
0x9605028

after deletion attempted

add of p1::0x9605028 add of p2::0x9605018 add of p3::0x9605028 add of p1->prev::0x9605018 add of p1->next::(nil) add of p2->prev::0x9605008 add of p2->next::0x9605028 add of p3->prev::0x9605018 add of p3->next::(nil)

no of nodes 3
```

In this example i am trying to delete the node 3 which is p3, by deleting its address 0x9605028. But after deletion the node count is still 3 and addresses are like unexpected!

Comment: I feel compelled to mention `temp = p1->next` introduces a memory leak on first invoke. The pointer `temp` was initialized near the top of the function as `temp=malloc(sizeof(struct dll))`. Its a pointer. C isn't Java. In fact, you could remove the declaration in `main()` entirely and declare a *local*-scope pointer inside the `if{}` braces (and it would probably be clearer if you did just that).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, but I didn’t understand the memory leak part, if you don't mind please take some more time to explain me clearly why memory leak?! I am in a lot of confusion actually because of linked lists.

Comment: The code should check for the correct node pointer before checking if node...next is null.  I.E. the following needs fixed:  while (p1->next != NULL) {
        if (p1->next == add) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not reinitializing your variables.

After the first "count" trip, `p1` is actually pointing to the third element in the list, and it's never put back to the beginning (in fact, you don't store the position of the beginning of the loop).  So from then on, `p1->next!=NULL` is false.  Neither of the other two loops run.

Notice that the address you output for `p1` after the "deletion" is the same as that for `p3`.  You're only getting the same count because you never set `count` back to zero before attempting to count again.

Comment: Thank you! Yes from now onwards I will take care!

Answer (score 2):

After this loop

```
while(p1->next!=NULL)
{
    count++;
    p1=p1->next;
}
```

p1->next is equal to NULL. Now p1 points to the same node as p3. So you have a memory leak.

As p1->next is equal to NULL then this loop

```
while(p1->next!=NULL)
{
    if(p1->next==add)
    {
        temp = p1->next;
        p1->next=NULL;
        free(temp);
        temp=NULL;
    }
    else
    p1=p1->next;
}
```

will be iterated never.

Also there is no any need to allocate memory for pointer temp

```
temp=malloc(sizeof(struct dll));
```

If you want to count the number of nodes then the code could look the following way

```
int count = 0;

for ( temp = p1; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next ) ++count;
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes from now onwards I will take care! Your answer is also correct, helped me but I can't accept two answers! Don't mind!

Answer (score 1):

Another problem you will have is that when you finally delete a node you will break the linked list unless you reset the next and previous ponters. Here's some logic on how to do it.

1. create a pointer to point to the node you want to delete, let's call it deleteMe
2. Create another pointer to point the either the previous or next node of deletMe.
3. Then reset your links.

   (deleteMe->previous)->next = deleteMe->next;

   (deleteMe->next)->previous = deleteMe->previous;
4. Now can you can free deleteMe
5. But make sure that you have a pointer to one of the remaining nodes in step 2 or you will lose the list in a memory leak.